# REST API - POST on endpoint , add 2 resources

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have request (POST) like this:

```
/car?manufacturer=BMW
```

or

```
/car?manufacturer=3
```

The thing is that manufacturer field is autocomplete, so If I choose one from manufacturers, I will send id: 3, if not I would like to send string there, and backend will be responsible to add car, and manufacturer in one request.

I think that this is better, my friend says that better is this one:

```
/manufacturer?name=BMW
/car?manufacturer=<id from last request on manufacturer>
```

Which one is better?

Regards

Comment: `manufacturer/<id>/car`?

Comment: According to single responsibility principle, one API should not try to handle more than one responsibility, so car API should not make entry into manufacturer. Hence I would side with your friend.

Comment: REST services are based on resources. Each resource should be handled in it's "designated" service. Hence it is recommended to create each resource in it's own service.